# Single data from the relation m2m field - Django

Tags: python, django, for-loop, many-to-many

In my signal (post_save), I would like to send a single email to a single person who has been assigned using the m2m relationship. One-to-many, the message goes to the user, but m2m nothing happens.

```
specials = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='special_users')
```

I've tried everything, searched the topics, but still nothing happens. I have included the pseudocode to illustrate the situation.

```
all_users_from_m2m = instance.specials.all()

    for single_user in all_users_from_m2m:
    
        message = ('Subject', 'Here is message', 'from@example.com', [single_user.email])
        send_mass_mail(message, fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if I understand your test case but there is a signal called m2m_changed. You could use it like so for instance:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

def on_some_model_specials_m2m_changed(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    # some actions here
    pass

m2m_changed.connect(
    on_some_model_specials_m2m_changed, sender=models.YourModel.specials.through)
```

Comment: In retrospect, I also recommend this signal.